# How to assign custom x labels on plot with uneven spacing

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create a graph with uneven 'x axis' and label them.

For example:

```
x = [2,5,10,20,30]
y = [100,200,312,788,123]
```

I want the x axis on plot to be spaced as x itself. I solved the issue with following code. But instead of exact x values I would like to name them in the order of occurrence, ie 1,2,3,4,5 in place of 2,5,10,20,30.

Thank you

```
plt.figure(30)
plt.plot(x,y,color='b',alpha=1)
plt.title('R_variation',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel(r'R',fontsize=20,color='k')
plt.xlabel('Time (hr)',fontsize=20,color='k')
plt.xticks(x, rotation='vertical')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not that hard to search through SO about relabeling, what about adding `labels=[1,2,3,4,5]` option to `plt.xticks`?

Comment: It takes the values of x, starting from 0. So the x axis label stop at 5 instead of 30, and that too with uniform spacing. I have been searching and trying for hours on this silly issue sadly :(

Comment: I guess you need to be more clear about expected output in your post to increase the chances for your question to be answered here. I got confused about how should desired spacing of labels to look like too.

Comment: I guess that you need to use `x=[6,12,18,24,30]` as `xticks` and label it as `[2,5,10,20,30]`. You might like to try `range`, `numpy.arange` or `numpy.linspace` methods for linear axis padding then.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I am adjusting my avoiding xtick display now with "tick_params(labelbottom=False)", and keeping grid on to show the uneven spacing.